# jQuery color change only flashes briefly, is not permanent

Tags: jquery, html, css, html-lists

I am trying to get a list item to change font color permanently when it is clicked upon, in this case from green to yellow. However, the code below only flashes yellow for half a second when it's clicked and then defaults to green. The underline styling is applied permanently though, as expected:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
     <script type = "text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.0.min.js"></script>
     <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('li').hover(function(){
                $(this).css('color', 'white')
             }, function(){
                $(this).css('color', '')
            });

            $("#resources").click(function(){
        $("#resources").css('text-decoration', 'underline');
        document.getElementById("resources").style.color = "yellow";
      });
        });
        </script>
        <style>
         #main{
          margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
    background: black;
    color: green;
    font-family: Courier;
    position: relative;
    top: 300px;
    width: 100%;
   }

         li{
       display: inline;
       padding: 8px;
       padding-right: 1em;
       position: relative;
     }
         li:hover{
       color: white;
   }
      ul{
       text-align: center;
      }

         </style>
     </head>
    <body>
     <div id = "main">
      <ul id = "main_links">
       <li id = "resources">Resources</li>
      </ul>
     </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try substituting `.mouseenter()` , `.mouseleave()` for `.hover()` ; calling  `.off()` of `$(this)` within `#resources` `.click()` event

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('li').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).css('color', 'white')
  }).mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).css('color', '')
  });

  $("#resources").click(function() {
    $(this).css({
        "text-decoration": "underline"
        , "color": "yellow"
      })
      .off("mouseenter mouseleave")
  });

});
```

```css
#main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  background: black;
  color: green;
  font-family: Courier;
  position: relative;
  top: 300px;
  width: 100%;
}
li {
  display: inline;
  padding: 8px;
  padding-right: 1em;
  position: relative;
}
li:hover {
  color: white;
}
ul {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>


<body>
  <div id="main">
    <ul id="main_links">
      <li id="resources">Resources</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's because the second function of your hover function is resetting the color.  Do you even need the li hover function at all?  That styling should be applied by CSS.  If you remove that, my guess is that the color should stay yellow even after you click on it.

Answer (score 0):

It stays yellow only until you move the mouse off of it because of the following code:

```
        $('li').hover(function(){
            $(this).css('color', 'white')
            }, function(){
            $(this).css('color', '')
        });
```

You could get rid of that code and add the following style:

```
li.clicked {
    color: yellow;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

And change the javascript to just:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#resources").click(function () {
        $(this).addClass('clicked');
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mksLeuty/)